# Quotient modules over a finite dimensional algebra

Tags: representation-theory

Let $M$ be a reducible finite dimensional $A$-module, where $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field of characteristic zero. $M$ admits an $A$-submodule $S$ and we can define the $A$-module $M_S:=M/S$. Now, if $M_S$ is reducible, we can define again the $A$-module $M_S/N$, where $N$ is a submodule of $M_S$. One can continue like that and my question is if there is an end to this procedure. I mean, is there a point where the quotient module is irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no" in general. No need for complicated examples, take $A=k=\Bbb Q$ and $M=\Bbb Q[X]$ with $S$ the submodule of constant polynomials; then $M/S\cong M$ to the process can be repeated indefinitely.

Now that you have added "finite dimensional" (I suppose over $k$) the answer is obviously "yes" (provided you forbid the "cheating" choice $S=\{0\}$), since $\dim_k M$ is strictly decreasing, and a $1$-dimensional module is necessarily irreducible.

Comment: Thank you! I just added that $M$ is finite dimensional. What happens in this case?

Comment: Thank you again! I mean finite dimensional as $A$-module.

Comment: Well "dimension" supposes a field, so it does really make sense as $A$-module (though you could say "finitely generated"). Anyway, with $A$ itself being a finite dimensional algebra the notions are the same.